# Model classes, json encoding and inheritence

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make the following flow work, I have a lot of model classes containing data for different types requests, I need to encode them to JSON according to the class structure.

I cant find the swift way to achieve that.

When I define `RequestType` as a class I'm forced to implement `init(from decoder: Decoder)` which is unnecessary for all the flat data model classes.

On the other hand, when I define `RequestType` as a protocol, I cant use `JSONEcoder()` on the variable in `request()` since Codable does not conform to codeble.

```
// super type
protocol RequestType: Codable {

}

// model class
class InitiateSignInRequest: RequestType {
    var phone: String

    init(_ phone: String) {
        self.phone = phone
    }
}

 // a function that needs to handle all model classes
 private func request(data: RequestType, // cant use codable here... it does not conform to itself {


        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let encodedData = try! encoder.encode(data)
        let postPayload = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)!
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
protocol RequestType: Codable {

}

extension RequestType {
    typealias T = Self
    func encode() -> Data? {
        return try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func decode(data: Data) -> T? {
        return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
}

private func request(data: RequestType) {
    let encodedData = data.encode()!
    let postPayload = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)!

}
```

OR you can just do it like it was intended (using a concrete class type):

```
protocol RequestType: Codable {

}

class CodeableModel : RequestType {

}

// model class
class InitiateSignInRequest: CodeableModel {
    var phone: String

    init(_ phone: String) {
        self.phone = phone
        super.init()
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        fatalError("init(from:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

private func request(data: CodeableModel) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let encodedData = try! encoder.encode(data)
    let postPayload = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)!

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) !

> ObjectMapper is a framework written in Swift that makes it easy for
>   you to convert your model objects (classes and structs) to and from
>   JSON.

ObjectMapper uses the `<-` operator to define how each member variable maps to and from JSON.

```
class User: Mappable {
    var username: String?
    var age: Int?
    var weight: Double!
    var array: [Any]?
    var dictionary: [String : Any] = [:]
    var bestFriend: User?                       // Nested User object
    var friends: [User]?                        // Array of Users
    var birthday: Date?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        username    <- map["username"]
        age         <- map["age"]
        weight      <- map["weight"]
        array       <- map["arr"]
        dictionary  <- map["dict"]
        bestFriend  <- map["best_friend"]
        friends     <- map["friends"]
        birthday    <- (map["birthday"], DateTransform())
    }
}
```

Comment: not what I asked, the question is about swift language and the relation between objects, super types and so on..... the json encoding part, not the important part

Comment: >I have a lot of model classes containing data for different types requests I need to encode them to JSON according to the class structure.
>I cant find the swift way to achieve that .   

Why not use ObjectMapper to conform your objects for encoding/decoding?

Comment: Also, are you calling your request(data:) method like this: `request(data: SomeRequestType.self` ?

Comment: im providing an instance request(InitiateSignInRequest("1800800800")

Comment: can you change your function signature to take an instance of the class you are passing to it i.e. `func request(data: InitiateSignInRequest,` instead of passing a reference of the protocol.